# How to know which image is touched/clicked in C# (mobile Coding)

Tags: c#, android

I am very new to C#. Now my situation is I have two different images, how do I know that which one is clicked/touched by user? Can I have both coding for clicked and the touched coding?

```
void Update () { 
   for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) { 
         if (imageA.transform.position.x == Input.GetTouch (i).position.x && imageA.transform.position.y == Input.GetTouch(i).position.y) { 
               textA.text = "Hello";
             } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is this for Windows Phone or MS Surface? WinForms? XAML?  _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: Can you show us some code so that we know what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click a image the `object sender` which is a parameter of the event fired gives you the information. You can cast it to type from which it is sent and it contains all the data .

```
private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Image image = sender as Image;
            //image is your image control and it has all its properties set
        }
```

Comment: I want to do if user touched/clicked image A ,it will display "Hello", if user touched/clicked image B, it will display "Bye". So how to do that?

Comment: do have names for your images??

Comment: in image object search for Name property and write a condition if(image.Name=="imageA"){ textA.Text="Hello";} else if(image.Name=="imageB"){ textA.Text="Bye";}